# Option Volatility and Pricing : value of a stock option will also depend on whether a trader has a long or short stock position

Tags: options, interest

Book: Option Volatility and Pricing
Chapter: Risk Measurement I
Topic: Change in interest rates can affect options

The value of a stock option will also depend on whether a trader has a long or short stock position. If a trader’s option position also includes a short stock position, he is effectively reducing the interest rate by the borrowing costs  required to sell the stock short . This will reduce the forward price, thereby lowering the value of calls and raising the value of puts. As a consequence, the trader who is carrying a short stock position ought to be willing to sell calls at a lower price or buy puts at a higher price. If the trader either sells calls or buys puts, he will hedge by purchasing stock, which will offset his short stock position.

The fact that option values depend on whether the trader hedges with long stock or short stock presents a complication that most traders would prefer to avoid. This leads to a useful rule for stock option traders: Whenever possible a trader should avoid a short stock position.

Doubts:
If a trader’s option position also includes a short stock position, he is effectively reducing the interest rate by the borrowing costs  required to sell the stock short. How?

the trader who is carrying a short stock position ought to be willing to sell calls at a lower price or buy puts at a higher price.
How?

Comment: Book section is 'Risk Measurement I'

Comment: Paragraph number 5 from start of chapter

Comment: Are you asking why short selling costs money (for borrowing/insurance that you can deliver later), or are you asking why additional costs reduce profit/interest rate?

Comment: 2 Doubts:
1) If a trader’s option position also includes a short stock position, he is effectively reducing the interest rate by the borrowing costs required to sell the stock short. How?

2) the trader who is carrying a short stock position ought to be willing to sell calls at a lower price or buy puts at a higher price. How?